# Magento 2 getting Error override resource model

Tags: magento2, error, overrides, resource-model

I have facing Below error when I override resource model

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable\Interceptor::getAttributeId() in /home/XXXXXX/Extendfiles/Plugin/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Type/Configurable.php on line 262
```

i have us this code

```
public function afterGetAttributeOptions($superAttribute, $productId) 
{ 
$scope = $this->getScopeResolver()->getScope(); 
$select = $this->getConnection()->select()->from( 
['super_attribute' => $this->getTable('catalog_product_super_attribute')], 
[ 
'sku' => 'entity.sku', 
'product_id' => 'product_entity.entity_id', 
'attribute_code' => 'attribute.attribute_code', 
'value_index' => 'entity_value.value', 
'option_title' => $this->getConnection()->getIfNullSql( 
'option_value.value', 
'default_option_value.value' 
), 
'default_title' => 'default_option_value.value', 
] 
)->joinInner( 
['product_entity' => $this->getTable('catalog_product_entity')], 
"product_entity.{$this->getProductEntityLinkField()} = super_attribute.product_id", 
[] 
)->joinInner( 
['product_link' => $this->getTable('catalog_product_super_link')], 
'product_link.parent_id = super_attribute.product_id', 
[] 
)->joinInner( 
['attribute' => $this->getTable('eav_attribute')], 
'attribute.attribute_id = super_attribute.attribute_id', 
[] 
)->joinInner( 
['entity' => $this->getTable('catalog_product_entity')], 
'entity.entity_id = product_link.product_id', 
[] 
)->joinInner( 
['entity_value' => $superAttribute->getBackendTable()], 
implode( 
' AND ', 
[ 
'entity_value.attribute_id = super_attribute.attribute_id', 
'entity_value.store_id = 0', 
"entity_value.{$this->getProductEntityLinkField()} = " 
. "entity.{$this->getProductEntityLinkField()}", 
] 
), 
[] 
)->joinLeft( 
['option_value' => $this->getTable('eav_attribute_option_value')], 
implode( 
' AND ', 
[ 
'option_value.option_id = entity_value.value', 
'option_value.store_id = ' . $scope->getId(), 
] 
), 
[] 
)->joinLeft( 
['default_option_value' => $this->getTable('eav_attribute_option_value')], 
implode( 
' AND ', 
[ 
'default_option_value.option_id = entity_value.value', 
'default_option_value.store_id = ' . \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID, 
] 
), 
[] 
)->where( 
'super_attribute.product_id = ?', 
$productId 
)->where( 
'option_value.value != "N/A"', 
$productId 
)->where( 
'attribute.attribute_id = ?', 
$superAttribute->getAttributeId() 
); 

return $this->getConnection()->fetchAll($select); 
}
i have just add my code at bottom of this function
->where( 
'option_value.value != "N/A"', 
$productId 
)
```

Di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable"> 
<plugin name="ptgConfigurableProduct" type="Modulename\Extendfiles\Plugin\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable" sortOrder="1" /> 
</type>
```

If anyone facing and get solution please  reply me.

Comment: please share proper log...`Extendfiles_Plugin` is  Seems your created extesnsion

Comment: Also share you full code of `/home/XXXXXX/Extendfiles/Plugin/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Type/Configurable.php`.

Answer (score 0):

There are mistakes in your plugin. You have not added the $subject and other function arguments correctly.

Try this

```
public function afterGetAttributeOptions(
    \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable $subject,
    $result,
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute $superAttribute,
    $productId
) {
    // add your code here
}
```

Comment: 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Strict Notice: Declaration of XXXXXXX\Extendfiles\Plugin\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable\Interceptor::afterGetAttributeOptions() should be compatible with XXXXXXX\Extendfiles\Plugin\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable::afterGetAttributeOptions(Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute $superAttribute, $productId) in /home/commercestaging/public_html/alpha/oly/var/generation/XXXXXXX/Extendfiles/Plugin/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Type/Configurable/Interceptor.php on line 7

Comment: I have to getting this error

Comment: Remove `var/generation` folder and try again.